# adding element after formtastic label

Tags: formtastic

I'm working with some existing code that looks something like this:

```
ff.input :answer_id,
  :as => :surveyor_radio,
  :collection => [[a_text(a, nil, render_context).html_safe, a.id]],
  :label => false, 
  :input_html => {:class => "someclass"),
  :response_class => a.response_class
```

and generates something like this html:

```
<li class="choice">
  <label for="123">
    <input class="someclass" id="123" name="foo" type="radio" value="bar" />
      BAR
  </label>
</li>
```

I'd like to add a paragraph of explanatory text betwee the closing  and the closing , like this:

```
<li class="choice">
  <label for="123">
    <input class="someclass" id="123" name="foo" type="radio" value="bar" />
      BAR
  </label>
  <p>It is really important that you understand all of this information about BAR before you pick it, so read this carefully.</p>
</li>
```

I haven't had much luck finding a way to do this.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What is this `:surveyor_radio` input type that you are using? Is it custom, or did you mean `:radio`?

Comment: I just meant radio and mistyped.  We ended up just putting the instructions at the very top, before the list.

Comment: Well, just in case you ever need this again in the future, it looks like Formtastic has a `:hint` option that might do what you wanted: `f.input :attribute, :hint => 'Stuff the user should know.'`.

Comment: But if you happen to need something more arbitrary than `:hint`, see the most recent answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10603124/how-to-embed-raw-html-in-active-admin-formtastic